# Zend: не работает update query

Tags: php, zend-framework, mysql

Добрый день,

Пытаюсь настроить запрос, но не получается. Помогите, пожалуйста, найти проблему.

```
$sql_code = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.item_code = table2.item_code WHERE status = 1");
$rows2 = $sql_code->fetchAll();

foreach ($rows2 as $key => $item2) {
    $db->update("table1", $rows2, "item_code = $item2->item_code");
}
```

Заранее спасибо

Comment: ваш код говорит, что вы делаете все не так и не хотите смотреть в документацию

Comment: И как мне ваш комментарий поможет? Укажите хоть, где ошибки, а то лиж бы воду лить

Comment: Zend какой версии?

Answer (score 1):

[@olafmeister](/users/22562/olafmeister), мне кажется, $rows2 в update лишние.